# Axis Change soap:address

Tags: java, axis

I've a Apache2 HTTP Server this server is avaliable to external networks. For my webservices I've a Jboss 4 in a internal network. I configured VirtualHosts on Apache with DMZ, so I can access the services from external hosts by `http://externalserver/services/SomeService?wsdl`, and when requests arraive with /services/* I'm redirect the request to `http://internalserver/services/SomeService?wsdl` by ProxyPass.

This working on intranet, but when I try consume my webservice from a external host, my wsdl refers to internal host. I've something like this:

```
<service name="SomeServiceService">
    <port binding="tns:SomeServiceBinding" name="SomeServicePort">
         <soap:address location="http://internalserver/services/SomeService"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

I need to change the location attribute in my generated wsdl, How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

I can change host and port I edited the jboss-beans.xml, Now I've something like this:

```
<property name="webServiceHost">${jboss.bind.address}</property>
<property name="modifySOAPAddress">true</property>
<property name="webServiceSecurePort">8443</property>
<property name="webServicePort">8080</property>
```

But this don't change the protocol, I can call `http://myapp/Service?wsdl` or `https://myapp/Service?wsdl` but in both the addres is http, I need change it to https.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://community.jboss.org/thread/205925) you can set `soap:address` to something like `"https://REPLACE-ME` as a work around, or enforce `CONFIDENTIAL` transport Guarantee (which may break your intranet services, unless you also deploy it in a https enabled server or replace the `soap:address` manually).